# Making a <div/> match the responsive size of its container

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, responsive-design

How would you make a div with text (or other elements) match the size of its container without causing it to overflow? The size of the container is dynamic and responsive, depending on the size of other elements or text within it, and is not strictly defined.

```
        <div style={{
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            backgroundColor: 'yellow'
        }}>
            <div style={{
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                backgroundColor: 'red'
            }}>
                This is a short sentence.
            </div>
            
            <div style={{
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                backgroundColor: 'blue'
            }}>
                This is a long sentence. I want it to fit into the bounds created by the short sentence in the div above.
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add these two properties to the div with the long sentence:

```
flexShrink: 1, /* Allows this div to shrink */
flexBasis: 'auto', /* Allows the width to be determined by the content */
```

Additionaly you can add `flex-shrink: 0` to the div with short sentences to prevent shrinking also add `height: '100%'` and `width: '100%'` to the parent div to ensure that it is allowing the content to resize dynamically.